# Gmail API sending limits

Tags: vb.net, email, gmail-api

I saw in some articles that the sending limit for gmail is:

*500 per day if we send by website

*100 per day if we send by pop/imap application

My questions are:

1.- The "100 per day" limit its also for an vb net apps that we can make?

2.- How many mails can be send using gmail API (or how many recipients)?

3.- How can I extend the limit with a FREE account?

Regards.

Comment: Gmail sending limits: https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en I think regardless of how you send them, code or UI, the limits apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [Usage Limits](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota) page of the Gmail API documentation, we have about 1,000,000,000 quota units per day for Daily Usage and 250 units/user/second rate limit.

All method transactions have allocated quota units, if we're specifically looking at the `send` method (either from drafts/messages), it will cost us 100 units.